# XML File Breaks abruptly

Tags: xml

We are trying to implement Single Sign-On with our client's ADFS.

To debug the issue, we have put the SSO Application Endpoint URL is put in the address bar and we enabled the Network Monitor to begin the trace and saved the trace in an XML file.

We have reached our client's ADFS page and we reviewed our XML file trace.

The XML file is broken at the below point.

[image: Invalid XML]

We have just landed on the Client's ADFS page and not even entered the User Credentials. But the XML file seems to be broken.

What should we do to resolve the issue?

Comment: What makes you think the XML is "broken"?  To me, it looks like the XML just  contains an HTML document embedded & escaped within it.

Comment: Thanks for the response jwodder. I had never seen an XML like this, so I thought it was broken. We did not know that XML could contain HTML document embedded in it.

Answer (score 0):

it's not broken, it's html-encoded inside the `<text>` element. if you html-decode the text inside the `<text>` element, you'll see it's actually html when decoded.

here's a simple decoding script if you don't have any readily available: https://3v4l.org/jj3Ep

```
<?php
$xml_html_encoded=<<<'THEXML'
&lt;text&gt;put your html-encoded html here&lt;/text&gt;

THEXML;

echo html_entity_decode($xml_html_encoded);
```

output:

```
<text>put your html-encoded html here</text>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response hanshenrik. It is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure the xml is well formed, you can use xmllint to validate it:

```
xmllint --noout client.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Cole.